# How do I create a docker container with two network interfaces but on the same network

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I need to reproduce a scenario where there are two machines on a network. Machine 1 has two network interfaces (say for control and data traffic), both on the same network.

```
 -------------                -------------
|     M 1     |              |     M 2     |
| eth0   eth1 |              |    eth0     |
1.1.1.1  1.1.1.2             |  1.1.1.3    |
|  |      |   |              |     |       |
 -------------                -------------
   |      |                        |
   +------+--network 1.1.1.0/24----+
```

I see there are solutions to have two networks on a docker container, but is it possible to have two interfaces on the same network in docker?